# SharePoint ASP.NET Mock Site

Tags: sharepoint, templates

Does any one know if there is a ASP.NET website available that is a pretty good clone of the style and layout of a SharePoint site?  I don't need the functionality of SharePoint, I would like to be able to quickly mock up some controls for SharePoint, with out having to actually deploy stuff to the server, and want to be able to see what the controls would look like rendered in SharePoint.

Make sense?

If there is nothing available I'm just going to do a "save complete" with FireFox on my SharePoint site, and convert the results into a master page that I can use.  If someone else has already done the work, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heather Solomon has an excellent SharePoint CSS Cheat Sheet. Also, if you use sharepoint native controls like the SPGridView, most of the styling will be inherited / already implemented for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'Save Complete' idea is the one I would suggest. You could also have some sort of bookmarklet/script that receives a html page url and injects it into the sharepoint page without actually changing it, but it is way more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use SharePoint Designer to play with the design and to use Features for deploying the customizations. Your question is pretty vague in that I can't tell if you have access to a VM to do a test install? Also, are we talking WSS 3.0 or MOSS 2007 or the latest version? Is it a publishing site? What kind of controls are you working on? Web Parts?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of details.  MOSS 2007 Publishing site.  Working on WebParts.  I'm creating a few facebook controls and I want to quickly see what they will look like in my sharepoint environment with out having to deploy the parts.  I do have access to a SharePoint development farm, but it's much faster to mock this stuff up in a regular asp.net website rather than waiting for WSPBuilder=>BuildWSP   WSPBuilder=>Deploy  wait for IIS to recycle app pools, wait for website to come back online etc..

Comment: It's as much work to mock it up in ASP.NET. Deploying Web Parts is now just a click of a button. Also, you want to use the SharePoint specific namespace as opposed to the ASP.NET one for Web Part. I've posted a blog on the steps: http://www.codersbarn.com/?tag=/webpart I'm presuming here that you are using a dev VM?